# sparse matrix multiplication using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, sparse-matrix

I am trying to speed up a sparse matrix multiplication calculation where the data is in `data.tables`.  Here's some code to create instances.

```
require(data.table)
require(tictoc)

#size of matrices (increase value of N to get bigger matrices)
N <- 10
mat1sz <- c(100, 1000)*N
nrow1 <- .01*mat1sz[1]*mat1sz[2]

mat2sz <- c(mat1sz[2], 50*N)
nrow2 <- .005*mat2sz[2]*mat2sz

#sparse matrices as data.tables
dt1 = data.table(i=sample(1:mat1sz[1], nrow1, replace=T), j=sample(1:mat1sz[2], nrow1, replace=T))
dt1 <- unique(dt1)[, val1:=runif(.N)][]

dt2 = data.table(j=sample(1:mat2sz[1], nrow2, replace=T), k=sample(1:mat2sz[2], nrow2, replace=T))
dt2 <- unique(dt2)[, val2:=runif(.N)][]
```

Actual calculation

```
setkey(dt1, i, j)
setkey(dt2, j)

joinagg <- function(x) {
    dt1[.(x)][dt2, .(i,k,val=val1*val2), on=.(j), nomatch=0, allow.cartesian=T][, .(val=sum(val)), .(i,k)]
    #dt1[.(x)][dt2, .(val=sum(val1*val2)), on=.(j), nomatch=0, by=.(i,k)] 
}

nc <- 60
ids <- unique(dt1[,i])
chunks <- unname(split(ids, sort(rep_len(1:nc, length(ids)))))

tic(); dt5 <- rbindlist(lapply(chunks, joinagg)); toc()
```

I was wondering if it was possible to speed up function `joinagg` by combining inner join and aggregate in one `[]`.  I tried to do that in the commented line in the function but that does not work.   Or is there a different `data.table` based approach which is fast and memory efficient?

Comment: Have you benchmarked this with ordinary sparse matrix multiplication?

Comment: I did and that is MUCH faster (click on the _edited ... hours ago_ link above and you will see that was in the previous version).  I wanted a `data.table` only solution since all the data is already in that format.